# yeoman : jit-grunt error with grunt serve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm trying to use to build angular app using yeoman and Grunt.
But when I try to launch the app using 'grunt serve' I got this error

```
grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

jit-grunt: Plugin for the "wiredep" task not found.
If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "wiredep" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-10-24 09:44:44 UTC)
loading tasks                175ms  ███████████████████ 55%
serve                         43ms  █████ 14%
loading grunt-contrib-clean   51ms  ██████ 16%
clean:server                  44ms  █████ 14%
Total 317ms
```

I tried to set the Static mappings in Grunfile.js as indicated in https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings but still show the same error.

Is there a way to solve it.
Thank in advance

ps: I'm using windows 10, 64 bit

Comment: did you solve this problem. I also have the same issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, try to install grunt-wiredep like this : https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep

Comment: Thanks @Fares, I got around this problem by cleaning and pulling the source again. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try installing grunt-wiredep:
npm install --save-dev grunt-wiredep

More details https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep